# Passing pointers to arrays of unrelated, but compatible, types without copying?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

(Disclaimer: At this point, this is mostly academic interest.)

Imagine I have such an external interface, that is, I do not control it's code:

```
// Provided externally: Cannot (easily) change this:

// fill buffer with n floats:
void data_source_external(float* pDataOut, size_t n);

// send n data words from pDataIn:
void data_sink_external(const uint32_t* pDataIn, size_t n);
```

**Is it possible within standard C++ to "move" / "stream" data between these two interfaces without copying?**

That is, is there any way to make the following be non-UB, without copying of the data between two correctly typed buffers?

```
int main()
{
  constexpr size_t n = 64;
  float fbuffer[n];
  data_source_external(fbuffer, n);

  // These hold and can be checked statically:
  static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "same size");
  static_assert(alignof(float) == alignof(uint32_t), "same alignment");
  static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559 == true, "IEEE 754");
  
  // This is clearly UB. Any way to make this work without copying the data?
  const uint32_t* buffer_alias = static_cast<uint32_t*>(static_cast<void*>(fbuffer));

  // **Note**: 
  // + reinterpret_cast would also be UB.

  data_sink_external(buffer_alias, n);
  // ...
```

---

As far as I can tell the following would be defined behavior, at least with regard to strict aliasing:

```
...
uint32_t ibuffer[n];
std::memcpy(ibuffer, fbuffer, n * sizeof(uint32_t));
data_sink_external(ibuffer, n);
```

but given that the `ibuffer` will have exactly the same bits as the `fbuffer` this seems quite insane.

Or would we [expect optimizing compilers to optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63368482/321013) even this copy away? (In a now deleted comment-like answer a user posted a [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/rec54j) that seems to indicate, at least on first glance, that clang 11 indeed would be able to optimize out the memcpy.)

Comment: Short Answer: No.  C++ doesn't really allow treating one type as another.  There are a couple exceptions, but none apply here.

Comment: If only data_sink_external had accepted plain old "chars", then at least there would have been a chance...

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/z/KvE8dn) might work as long as `n` is known at compile time.  Although I find it odd that GCC was able to optimize the conversion between the arrays but not inline the function, on the other hand Clang wasn't able to optimize the conversion, but was able to do it once it was inlined in `main`.

Comment: Using `std::bit_cast` and `std::array` both compilers like it a bit better ([demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/fhrqqb))

Answer (score -2):

I didn't test and can't comment yet (cause not enough reputation). But reinterpret_cast may help in this situation.

[Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Basically it tells the compiler, hey treat this pointer as if it was the specified type in the cast.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` for this purpose violates strict aliasing rules. It will probably look like it works in most tests, but it is Undefined Behavior. Read the "Type aliasing" section of the site you linked.

Comment: There's no difference in doing the `static_cast` to void and then to a different type here compared to `reinterpret_cast`. The question is not "how", but is it allowed by the standard. Notice the language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux after using `reinterpret_cast`, the first thing which is likely to be violated is not strict aliasing rules, but https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#6.sentence-1

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Neither the C nor C++ Standard has ever made a reasonable effort to enumerate all corner cases that were processed consistently by all or nearly all commonplace implementations and should have continued to be so.  It would seem implausible that the authors of the earlier standards did not intend that PODS with the same size and representation be treated as compatible in far more cases than mandated.